# Theme inheritance : blocks placement not inherited

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have a "Father" theme, and a "Child" theme that inherits from Father.

Css and templates are well inherited, it's ok, but blocks placement (Structure > Blocks) won't inherit.

Is it supposed to ? If it is, do you have any idea for this to work ?

Note : I have the same custom regions defined in each .info file.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block placement per region is unique to each theme. Putting the search block in "right_sidebar" for theme_a doesn't put the search block in "right_sidebar" for theme_b.

Comment: Ok, in other words, no inheritance for blocks placement ?

Comment: That is correct.